# extract single frame from video

Tags: python, ubuntu

I am trying to write a script that will extract a single frame from a user uploaded video clip in order to create a thumbnail. It sounds like either OpenCV or ffmpeg will do what I need, but I am having trouble installing them.

I tried installing OpenCV using `apt-get install libopencv-dev`, and it looks like everything worked, but when running `import cv2` in Python, it says there is no such module. Also tried installing using [these instructions](http://karytech.blogspot.com/2012/05/opencv-24-on-ubuntu-1204.html), but when I run the import, it hangs for a second or two and then says `Failed to initialize libdc1394`.

I then tried to install ffmpeg with pyffmpeg, but the most recent version of pyffmpeg I could find was released 3 years ago and built for Python2.6 on Ubuntu 10.10, while I am using 2.7 on Ubuntu 12.04.

Does anyone have experience installing either of these, or would recommend something else for this purpose?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extract Video Frames In Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10672578/extract-video-frames-in-python)

Comment: @njzk2 that link popped up in my searches before posting this. It doesn't address the installation/import problems I am having for either OpenCV or ffmpeg

Comment: You should install cv2 with 'pip install opencv-python'

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to install ffmpeg, you can do this more easily if you have homebrew and then use brew to install it. It's a lot more complicated otherwise.

If you just want to be able to complete this task, and it doesn't have to be the tool you're listing, you could try [ffmpeg-python](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python/tree/master/examples). After you have it installed, you can use the [get_video_thumbnail](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python/blob/master/examples/get_video_thumbnail.py) example to get a single image. You could also probably tweak the [read_frame_as_jpeg](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python/blob/master/examples/read_frame_as_jpeg.py) example to get a single image from a frame if you want.

Comment: Doesn't ffmpeg-python requires ffmpeg to be installed and referenced in the user's path?

Comment: Yes which is why I mention that you should use homebrew to install ffmpeg if possible. Installation process would be: 

1. Install ffmpeg with homebrew 
2. Install ffmpeg-python with pip