# take frame every hour from youtube live video and create a timeelapse video

Tags: python, video-capture, youtube-livestreaming-api

I would like creating a script in order to take every hour a frame from a youtube live video and I create a timelapse video.
Could someone help me?

Comment: Please add some code so that we could help you.

Comment: I'm trying to create a draft code, if you can suggest me a start point.... It would be glad...

Comment: You can start with the cv2 module. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33311153/python-extracting-and-saving-video-frames)

Comment: @user8212173 thanks for suggestion