# extracting frames from video

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I am trying to extract frames from video, i am using this code:

```
import cv2
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('video_01.mp4')
success,image = vidcap.read()
count = 0
success = True
while success:
  success,image = vidcap.read()
  print('Read a new frame: ', success)
  cv2.imwrite("frame%d.jpg" % count, image)     # save frame as JPEG file
  count += 1
```

This returns

> Read a new frame:  False

Ihave followed various posts about this in SO. I installed ffmepg, av but nothing works.

I am running it on windows, installed opencv via Anaconda.

What is workaround for this? Thanks for help

I also tried

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os

# Playing video from file:
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('example.mp4')

try:
    if not os.path.exists('data'):
        os.makedirs('data')
except OSError:
    print ('Error: Creating directory of data')

currentFrame = 0
while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Saves image of the current frame in jpg file
    name = './data/frame' + str(currentFrame) + '.jpg'
    print ('Creating...' + name)
    cv2.imwrite(name, frame)

    # To stop duplicate images
    currentFrame += 1

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

However this saves empty images

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33311153/python-extracting-and-saving-video-frames

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - Extracting and Saving Video Frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33311153/python-extracting-and-saving-video-frames)

Comment: i tried the solutions and it didnt work

Comment: Oh, I do apologize then you need an alternative way. How come that it saves empty files, does it read it properly that's the question? Does it support the  filetype and is the encoding of the file same.

Comment: i tried mp4 or mpeg. I am not sure how i can test if it read the video properly

Comment: Did you download the same video from the answer in the post @ElvirMuslic shared? You need to make sure the video is in the same folder as the python script.

Answer (score 0):

How about change while loop in second code (15th line) to this

```
while(cap.isOpened()):
```

from

```
while(True):
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems your code has no problem,
please try to run this command:

```
pip install opencv-python
```