# Eliminating redundant frames in a video using Python

Tags: python, video, video-capture, opencv

I was looking at a real time problem where we need to eliminate the redundant frames of a video.(May be a video with lyrics of a song) 
In my example, lyrics video song, we are not concerned about the audio. Only frames containing the lyrics. but the thing is 2 line of lyrics my end up with 20seconds ending up with multiple frames having the same lyrics. So I was interested in eliminating those redundant frames.

While searching, I have found this code to extract frames from a video by this - [Python - Extracting and Saving Video Frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33311153/python-extracting-and-saving-video-frames)

```
 import cv2
 vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('Compton.mp4')
 success,image = vidcap.read()
 count = 0
 success = True
 while success:
 success,image = vidcap.read()
 cv2.imwrite("frame%d.jpg" % count, image)     # save frame as JPEG file
 if cv2.waitKey(10) == 27:                     # exit if Escape is hit
  break
 count += 1
```

Can you please help me how to proceed in order to eliminate the redundant frames from here on.

Answer (score 1):

I have had some luck in removing redundant frames in video streams using [pyscene detect](https://pyscenedetect.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

I'm gonna add the [relevant method](https://pyscenedetect.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/detection-methods/)  which you might find interesting -

### Content-Aware Detector

The content-aware scene detector (-d content) works the way most people think of "cuts" between scenes in a movie - given two frames, do they belong to the same scene, or different scenes? The content-aware scene detector finds areas where the difference between two subsequent frames exceeds the threshold value that is set (a good value to start with is --threshold 30).

This allows you to detect cuts between scenes both containing content, rather than how most traditional scene detection methods work. With a properly set threshold, this method can even detect minor, abrupt changes, such as jump cuts in film.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the frames(jpegs)then you can use ffmpeg video filter option and extract the frames at a given frame rate(fps)

`ffmpeg -i "Compton.mp4" -vf fps=1 frame%04d.jpg -hide_banner`

This will extract one frame a second. You can tweak it based on how frequently your lyrics change in the video.

If you want to use it in python then [ffmpeg-python](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python) is a great tool.

Hope it helps.

Comment: i don't want to manually set the frequency of taking frames, becz each song will have a different one right? instead i thought i could have a code to do some comparison from the frames  produced. (i hope my intention is in right direction)