# Get images of a streaming video url with Python

Tags: python, url, video, streaming, frames

I have this url
https://www.earthcam.com/js/video/embed.php?type=h264&vid=AbbeyRoadHD1.flv

And I want get frames from the streaming and save them in Python. Is this possible? I looked into the `streamlink` library, but I'm not sure if it will work. 
Sorry for my bad English, thanks.

```
streams = streamlink.streams("https://www.earthcam.com/js/video/embed.php?type=h264&vid=AbbeyRoadHD1.flv")
```

Answer (score -2):

Copied from this question: [Python - Extracting and Saving Video Frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33311153/python-extracting-and-saving-video-frames)

Try this:

```
import cv2
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('https://www.earthcam.com/js/video/embed.php?type=h264&vid=AbbeyRoadHD1.flv')
success,image = vidcap.read()
count = 0
while success:
    cv2.imwrite("frame%d.jpg" % count, image) # save frame as JPEG file      
    success,image = vidcap.read()
    print('Read a new frame: ', success)
    count += 1
```

Comment: I think cv2.Videocaoture() is for vídeos un local or webcams... I'm wrong? Thanks

Comment: This code does not work in OpenCV 3.4.2 ... I can't find any OpenCV documentation which states you can pass a URL to it.