# Extract image from Django media video file

Tags: django, opencv

I'm trying to store an image from a video file in django in the save method of a model.  I've based in on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33311153/python-extracting-and-saving-video-frames)

This is my save method for the model

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

    if not self.slug: 
        orig = self.slug = slugify(unidecode(self.name))
        for x in itertools.count(1):
            if not Project.objects.filter(slug=self.slug).exists() or (Project.objects.filter(slug=self.slug).exists() and self == Project.objects.get(slug=self.slug)):
                break
            self.slug = '%s-%d' % (orig, x)

    super(Project, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    if not self.image and self.project_type=='video':
        vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(settings.MEDIA_ROOT + self.video.url)
        success,image = vidcap.read()
        self.image = image
        self.image.name = 'video_images/' + self.slug + '.jpg'
        new_path = settings.MEDIA_ROOT + self.image.name
        cv2.imwrite(new_path, image)
        super(Project, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I've taken a look at `success` and it always comes out `False` (I've tried looping `while not success` and it eventually timesout)

Comment: why not `self.video.read()`?

Comment: I assume you mean replacing `success,image = vidcap.read()` with `success,image = self.video.read()`.  This gives `Too many values to unpack` error

Comment: does not need the `success` simple `image = self.video.read()`

Comment: I've tried without and image is then just a series of bytes and self.image.name crashes

Comment: rollback all your changes and do only:
`vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(settings.MEDIA_ROOT + self.video.url)` --> `vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(self.video.read())`

Comment: `vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(self.video.read())` errors `TypeError an integer is required (got type bytes)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the save to this.  It works when the video name is latin characters but not for Greek

```
    if not self.image and self.project_type=='video':
        vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(settings.BASE_DIR + self.video.url)
        success,image = vidcap.read()
        new_path = settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '/video_images/' + self.slug + '.jpg'
        cv2.imwrite(new_path, image)
        self.image = new_path
        self.image.name = 'video_images/' + self.slug + '.jpg'
```

Just realised it doesn't work when video has Greek character set