# Python - Extract frames from video without OpenCV

Tags: python, ffmpeg, image-segmentation

for semantic segmentation inference I'd like to extract frames of a video and run them through a network without using OpenCV's VideoCapture as something like (answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33311153/python-extracting-and-saving-video-frames)):

```py
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('testvideo.mp4')
```

the reason being that I don't want to install that package which is a bit heavy only to get frames from video.

What I currently do is getting the frames from a video with `ffmpeg` with:

```
ffmpeg -i testvideo.mp4 frames/%05d.png
```

And then load the frames, perform inference, and save the results. I've seen packages like [ffmpeg-python](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python) which have examples for how to load the video into numpy arrays, which I haven't managed to get working.

Comment: better show code which you tried to use.

Comment: as for me `OpenCV` is less heavy than using `ffmpeg`. Module  `cv2` accesses directly functions in library `OpenCV` and `modules like `ffmpeg-python` or `MoviePy` probably have to run subprocess to run external program `ffmpeg`

Comment: I'm not sure but `OpenCV` may use library `SDL` which is used also by `PyGame` - [pygame.camera](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/camera.html)