# How do I use threads to make an action wait for another action to finish before moving on?

Tags: python, video

I am training a deep learning model on a dataset of **100GB** of video data. I am trying to convert it all into frames before applying Haar Cascade on each frame to crop the faces out. But im trying to find the fastest way to do so.

[Link to the dataset](https://sites.google.com/view/utarldd/home)

**NOTE:**
There are **5 folds** each with **2 parts** in them. **Each part** has **6 folders** with **3 different categories** of data(**0, 5, 10**) in different video formats(**mp4, MOV, mov**). There are **144** video files in total and each is about **700MB** in size.

**EDIT:**
I am running into an issue where the processing of the video to frames is not waiting for its work to be done before going on to the next file

**Error Message:**
It immediately throws an error for each file instead of waiting to convert the frames of the current file then moving on to the next file.

```
Error!!!
Reading from /Volumes/HDD/Data/Fold4_part2/44/5.mov
Category:5
Writing to /Volumes/HDD/Data/Fold4_part2/44
Number of frames:  7353
Converting video..

Error!!!
Reading from /Volumes/HDD/Data/Fold4_part2/45/0.mp4
Category:0
Writing to /Volumes/HDD/Data/Fold4_part2/45
Number of frames:  7716
Converting video..
```

**Code:**

```
import cv2
import time 
import os
path_HDD = "/Volumes/HDD/Data"

def files(path):
    """
    Function to get the files and add them to a list 
    Args: 
        path: path of the file 
    Not sure what is DS_Store but I do not need it
    """
    for root, directories, files in os.walk(path, topdown=False):
        for name in files:
            file_path = os.path.join(root, name)
            if (name == ".DS_Store"):
                continue 
            else: 
                category = name.split(".")[0]
                # Category returns the video category 
                try: 
                    print("Reading from " + file_path)
                    print("Category:" + category)
                    print("Writing to " + root)
                    video_to_frames(file_path, category, root)
                except:
                    print("Error!!!")

 
        
def video_to_frames(input_loc, label,output_loc):
    """Function to extract frames from input video file
    and save them as separate frames in an output directory.
    Args:
        input_loc: Input video file.
        output_loc: Output directory to save the frames.
    Returns:
        None
    """
    # Log the time
    time_start = time.time()
    # Start capturing the feed
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(input_loc)
    # Find the number of frames
    video_length = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)) - 1
    print ("Number of frames: ", video_length)
    count = 0
    print ("Converting video..\n")
    # Start converting the video
    while cap.isOpened():
        # Extract the frame
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        # Write the results back to output location.
        cv2.imwrite(output_loc +  "/" + label + "/%#05d.jpg" % (count+1), frame)
        
        count = count + 1
        # If there are no more frames left
        if (count > (video_length-1)):
            # Log the time again
            time_end = time.time()
            # Release the feed
            cap.release()
            # Print stats
            print ("Done extracting frames.\n%d frames extracted" % count)
            print ("It took %d seconds forconversion." % (time_end-time_start))
            break

if __name__=="__main__":
    files(path_HDD)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve it with the help of the answer above but it would take probably 6 hours to process all 100GB. Not really an issue but I might find a way to make it faster using threading.

```
import cv2
import time 
import os
import argparse
import sys
path_HDD = "/Volumes/HDD/Data"

def files(path):
    """
    Function to get the files and add them to a list 
    Args: 
        path: path of the file 
    Not sure what is DS_Store but I do not need it
    """
    for root, directories, files in os.walk(path, topdown=False):
        for name in files:
            file_path = os.path.join(root, name)
            if (name == ".DS_Store"):
                continue 
            else: 
                category = name.split(".")[0]
                # Category returns the video category 
                try: 
                    print("Reading from " + file_path)
                    print("Category:" + category)
                    print("Writing to " + root)
                    video_to_frames(file_path, category, root)
                except:
                    sys.exit("Unable to extract the frames from the video!")
"""
Root : /Volumes/HDD/Data/Fold1_part1/01/
Category : Label of the video 
File path : 
"""
 
        
def video_to_frames(input_loc, label,output_loc):
    """Function to extract frames from input video file
    and save them as separate frames in an output directory.
    Args:
        input_loc: Input video file.
        output_loc: Output directory to save the frames.
    Returns:
        None
    """
    #Checking if the file exists before creating it 
    pathFrame = os.path.join(output_loc, label) 
    if (os.path.exists(pathFrame)):
        pass
    else:
        try:
            os.mkdir(pathFrame) 
            print("Directory '%s' created" %pathFrame) 
        except IOError:
            print("Unable to create the new directory")
            sys.exit()
        
    # Log the time
    time_start = time.time()
    # Start capturing the feed
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(input_loc)
    # Find the number of frames
    video_length = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)) - 1
    print ("Number of frames: ", video_length)
    count = 0
    print ("Converting video..\n")
    # Start converting the video
    while cap.isOpened():
        # Extract the frame
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        # Write the results back to output location.
        cv2.imwrite(pathFrame + "/%#05d.jpg" % (count+1), frame)
        count = count + 1
        # If there are no more frames left
        if (count > (video_length-1)):
            # Log the time again
            time_end = time.time()
            # Release the feed
            cap.release()
            # Print stats
            print ("Done extracting frames.\n%d frames extracted" % count)
            print ("It took %d seconds forconversion." % (time_end-time_start))
            break

if __name__=="__main__":
    files(path_HDD)
```

Answer (score 1):

This question is really two bundled into one.

1. How do I abstract all frames in one video?
2. How do I then scale up that process so I can apply it to entire directories.

You can achieve the 1st by using opencv-python by with [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33311153/python-extracting-and-saving-video-frames)

the 2nd should be achievable with a little bit of general Python knowledge and knowing how to get file paths with the [os module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-do-i-list-all-files-of-a-directory)

Comment: Ok i followed it but I am running into an issue. Please check the new edit.