# Split video into images with ffmpeg-python

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg

As far as I understand [`ffmpeg-python`](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python) is main package in Python to operate `ffmpeg` directly.

Now I want to take a video and save it's frames as separate files at some fps.

There are plenty of command line ways to do it, e.g. `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf fps=1 img/output%06d.png` [described here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20thumbnail%20image%20every%20X%20seconds%20of%20the%20video)

But I want to do it in Python. Also there are solutions [[1]](https://github.com/c0decracker/video-splitter) [[2]](https://github.com/alibugra/frame-extraction) that use Python's `subprocess` to call `ffmpeg` CLI, but it looks dirty for me.

Is there any way to to make it using `ffmpeg-python`?

Comment: looks like [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33311153/python-extracting-and-saving-video-frames) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you try [imageio module](https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html) and use the following code as a starting point:

```
import imageio

reader = imageio.get_reader('imageio:cockatoo.mp4')

for frame_number, im in enumerate(reader):
    # im is numpy array
    if frame_number % 10 == 0:
        imageio.imwrite(f'frame_{frame_number}.jpg', im)
```

Answer (score 5):

The following works for me:

```
ffmpeg
.input(url)
.filter('fps', fps='1/60')
.output('thumbs/test-%d.jpg', 
        start_number=0)
.overwrite_output()
.run(quiet=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [openCV](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/) for that.

Reference code:

```
import cv2

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture("your_video_path")
video_capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, <your_desired_fps_here>)

saved_frame_name = 0

while video_capture.isOpened():
    frame_is_read, frame = video_capture.read()

    if frame_is_read:
        cv2.imwrite(f"frame{str(saved_frame_name)}.jpg", frame)
        saved_frame_name += 1

    else:
        print("Could not read the frame.")
```

Comment: method `.set` returns `False`. That means FPS couldn't be set directly to VideoCapture.

I just skipped excess frames with `continue`

Answer (score 0):

@norus solution is actually good, but for me it was missing the ss and r parameters in the input. I used a local file instead of a url.

This is my solution:

```
  ffmpeg.input(<path/to/file>, ss = 0, r = 1)\
        .filter('fps', fps='1/60')\
        .output('thumbs/test-%d.jpg', start_number=0)\
        .overwrite_output()]
        .run(quiet=True)
```

ss is the starting second in the above code starts on 0
r is the ration, because the filter fps is set to 1/60 an r of 1 will return 1 frame per second, of 2 1 frame every 2 seconds, 0.5 a frame every half second....