# How to get the last frame of a video with imageio in python?

Tags: python, javax.imageio, python-imageio

I wanna grab 5 frames of a video distributed evenly including first and last frame. The answer to this helped me to loop over the video and get frames. However I didn't find out how to know when it's gonna be the last frame. Also looping over the whole video seems a bit expensive.

[Python - Extracting and Saving Video Frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33311153/python-extracting-and-saving-video-frames)

Is there a better way of getting 5 specific frames (e.g. every 20% of the video) or at least and easy way of getting the total frame number? I already tried multiplying duration and fps from the metadata, but those numbers seem to be rounded and give a wrong number.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not this is possible depends on your container and codec being used. Assuming the codec allows retrieving the total number of frames, you can do something like this:

```py
import imageio.v3 as iio
import numpy as np

my_video = "imageio:cockatoo.mp4"
props = iio.improps(my_video, plugin="pyav")

# Make sure the codec knows the number of frames
assert props.shape[0] != -1

for idx in np.linspace(0, props.shape[0]-1, 5, dtype=int):
    # imageIO < 2.21.0
    image = iio.imread(my_video, index=idx)
    # imageIO > 2.21.0
    # image = iio.imread(my_video, index=idx, plugin="pyav")
    iio.imwrite(f"delete_me/frame_{idx:03d}.png", image)
```

A few notes:

- you want to use pyav for the call to [`iio.improps`](https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_autosummary/imageio.v3.improps.html#imageio.v3.improps), because it doesn't decode frames, so it is fast.
- some codecs or containers (especially when streaming video) either don't report or can't report the number of frames stored within. In this case `props.shape[0]` will be `-1` and we can't use this method.
- normally I'd recommend using pyav for the `imread` call as well, but there is a bug in the plugin that causes an EoF exception when trying to `index=` to the last frame. This will be fixed by [#855](https://github.com/imageio/imageio/pull/855), though I can't say if it will make it into this weekly release or the next.
- if the codec used doesn't guarantee constant framerate, you won't get any speed advantages over `iio.imiter` because we can't safely predict how far into the video to seek. If you *know* that your video has a constant framerate, however, you can use the `constant_framerate` kwarg of the pyav plugin to speed things up. (IMPORTANT: if the video has variable framerate and you set this anyway the seek will not be accurate.)
- As usual, you can use `iio.imopen` if you want to do all of these operations without reopening the video each time.